# Выезжающие части окна wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте, при запуске программы открывается окно 1, затем по нажатии маленькой правой кнопки добовляется к нему блок 2, затем по нажатии следующей кнопки добавляется к ним блок 3, обведенный зеленым. Как это организовать? MainWindow как я понимаю это первое окно, размеры ему ставить как размеры блока 1, или как габариты 3го? Пока все что понял, блоки 2 и 3 должны быть  page и подключаться как frame. А далее все глухо в русском ,  а на английском сформулировать нормально не могу. Спасибо. И еще форма 3го блока не вызовет проблем?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Само окно приложения изначально размером с первый блок, а затем поэтапно увеличивается до размера как на скриншоте? Или окно сразу большого размера, и внутри нёго поэтапно появляются блоки?

Comment: Само окно при запуске выглядит как первый блок, т.е. маленькое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для авто-подгона размера окна под содержимое используйте свойство [`SizeToContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent(v=vs.110).aspx).
А блоки 1 и 2 просто расположите поверх блока 3 в гриде, указав им более высокий `ZIndex`.

```
<Window  ...  SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>

        <!-- Объединение блоков 1 и 2 чтобы они были поверх блока 3 -->
        <StackPanel ZIndex="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">

            <!-- Блок 1 -->
            <StackPanel Background="Orange" Width="300" Height="100">
            </StackPanel>

            <!-- Блок 2 -->
            <StackPanel Background="Red" Width="50" Height="100">
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>

        <!-- Блок 3 -->
        <StackPanel ZIndex="10" Background="Green" Width="600" Height="300">
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Я здесь не стал добавлять контент в панели (блоки) - для нагладности просто дал им разные бекграунды и фиксированный размер.

Дальше забиндите и управляйте свойством `Visibility` этих трёх панелей в соответствии с алгоритмом.